# Integrating sorbet with paper-trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem, sorbet

When I try and add a `has_paper_trail` on any of my models to include versioning for objects created, Sorbet throws the following error:

```
app/models/model_name.rb:22: Method `has_paper_trail` does not exist on `T.class_of(<ModelName>)` https://srb.help/7003
    22 |  has_paper_trail
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca should be able to generate the interface files (.rbi files) you need, based on the methods it finds at runtime. I would give that a shot.

Comment: https://sorbet.org/docs/rbi#quickref has a section to type your gems. Might help. Also the url that's included in the error message you have links to a site where it says you might need to manually include the module

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same issue. We're currently using the [tapioca](https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca) gem to generate RBI files on our project.

In order to resolve this I added `require 'paper_trail/frameworks/active_record'` to `sorbet/tapioca/require.rb` file and ran `bin/tapioca gem paper_trail` to regenerate the RBI file for the paper_trail gem.

Hope this helps.